# How do I get Postgres DO $$ to work from the bash prompt?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, scripting

Postgres 9.6.9 on Linux RHEL 6.10

If I surround my DO command in double-quotes and the roles in single quotes, then bash interprets the `$$`, and that obviously makes the command fail.  So I switched the double- and single-quotes, but now it treats the `NOT IN` string literals as column names, which also throws an error.

So, as mentioned in the title, what's the magic sauce for getting a `DO $$` command to work from the command line?

```
$ export PGHOST=10.x.y.z
$ export PGUSER=postgres
$ psql -c 'do $$  
>          declare rolename text;
>          begin
>            for rolename in select rolname 
>                            from pg_roles 
>                            where rolname not in ("postgres",
>                                                  "pg_signal_backend",
>                                                  "TAP")
>            loop
>            execute "DROP ROLE " || rolename;                   
>            end loop;
>          end $$
>          ;'
ERROR:  column "postgres" does not exist
LINE 3:                            where rolname not in ("postgres",...
                                                         ^
QUERY:  select rolname 
                           from pg_roles 
                           where rolname not in ("postgres", "pg_signal_backend", "TAP")
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at FOR over SELECT rows
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `\` to escape the dollar `$`

```
echo \$PATH
$PATH
```

Reference to [psql doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html), in order to execute multi commands, they also provide 3 ways to work around as below

*1) Repeats `-c` option*

```
psql -c 'SELECT now()' -c 'SELECT * FROM foo;'
```

*2) Combines `echo` and `psql`*

```
echo 'SELECT now() ; SELECT * FROM foo;' | psql
```

*3) Uses `psql` and `EOF`*

```
psql <<EOF
\x     
SELECT now(); 
SELECT * FROM foo;
EOF
```

Besides, considering changing `rolename text` to `rolename RECORD` to avoid `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table` ([record type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-declarations.html))

> Record variables are similar to row-type variables, but they have no
>   predefined structure. They take on the actual row structure of the row
>   they are assigned during a SELECT or FOR command

In terms of your case, please careful with `DROP ROLE` due to dependencies (refer: [dropping role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/role-removal.html))

> If DROP ROLE is attempted while dependent objects still remain, it
>   will issue messages identifying which objects need to be reassigned or
>   dropped.

Last but not least, here's my example

```
#### Using psql and EOF
psql << EOF
DO \$$
DECLARE
  v_role record; 
BEGIN
  for v_role in select rolname from pg_roles where rolname not in ('postgres', 'pg_signal_backend', 'TAP')
  loop
    raise notice '%', v_role.rolname;
    execute 'DROP ROLE ' || v_role.rolname;  
  end loop;
END
\$$;
EOF

#### Using echo and psql
echo "
DO \$$
DECLARE
  v_role record; 
BEGIN
  for v_role in select rolname from pg_roles where rolname not in ('postgres', 'pg_signal_backend', 'TAP')
  loop
    raise notice '%', v_role.rolname;
    execute 'DROP ROLE ' || v_role.rolname;  
  end loop;
END
\$$;
" | psql
```

Comment: "*Thus you cannot mix SQL and psql meta-commands*" Is `do $$` a meta-command? Or does escaping the `$` make psql *think* that it's a meta-command?

Comment: Anything you enter in `psql` that begins with an `unquoted backslash` is a psql meta-command.  So, `do $$` is not a psql meta-command. I will clarify my post a bit.

Comment: why not use .sql file? for multiline blocks - more easy. sql -d xxx < command.sql

Comment: @a_vlad: yes, I agree, that's easier.

Comment: @a_vlad because I don't like lots of tiny little one-purpose scripts floating around.

Comment: `$` does not even have to be escaped when parameter substitution is turned off. See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html for the full explanation with a dozen examples.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the syntax mentioned in the other answers didn't work.
How I was able to do it:

Run script in bash shell:

```
psql -h remotehost -p 5432 -U username dbname < ./scripts/sqlscript.sql
```

This will prompt you for the password and then run `sqlscript.sql`.
For the script itself, I used the pattern like in the

**Example `sqlscript.sql`:**

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
    delete
    from django_migrations
    where app like '%myapi%';
    RAISE NOTICE 'Deleted API related migration info';
END
$do$;
```

Comment: Note that a .pgpass file obviates the need for a password prompt.